# Admob Interstitial ad not showing up at all

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I basically copy-pasted and mildly modified the demo project ads setup by the official branch of this Google Mobile Ads and my banner ads show up all right, but no interstitial ads show up - no matter what.

Here's what I did, using my `AdManager static class`:

This `InitializeAds()` is called right after starting the game:

```
public static void InitializeAds()
{
    MobileAds.Initialize(appID);
}
```

And of course, every level where there is an ad, has the following `GetSomeAdRequests()` inside their `Start()` method.

```
public static void GetSomeAdRequests()
{
    AdRequestBANNER = CreateAdRequest();
    AdRequestINTERST = CreateAdRequest();
}

public static AdRequest CreateAdRequest()
{
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    return request;
}
```

Needless to say I use the tester video and banner IDs provided by Google.

Next, my `RequestInterstitial`:

```
public static void RequestInterstitial()
{
    // These ad units are configured to always serve test ads.
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    string adUnitId = "unused";
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
    string adUnitId = videoID;
    #else
    string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif

    // Clean up interstitial ad before creating a new one.
    if (interstitial != null)
    {
        interstitial.Destroy();
    }

    // Create an interstitial.
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);

    // Register for ad events.
    interstitial.OnAdLoaded += HandleInterstitialLoaded;
    interstitial.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad;
    interstitial.OnAdOpening += HandleInterstitialOpened;
    interstitial.OnAdClosed += HandleInterstitialClosed;
    interstitial.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleInterstitialLeftApplication;

    // Load an interstitial ad.
    interstitial.LoadAd(AdRequestINTERST);
    if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
    {
        interstitial.Show();
    }
}
```

And finally `AdRequestINTERST` is:

```
private static AdRequest adRequestINTERST;
public static AdRequest AdRequestINTERST
{
    get
    {
        if (adRequestINTERST == null)
        {
            adRequestINTERST = CreateAdRequest();
        }
        return adRequestINTERST;
    }
    set
    {
        adRequestINTERST = value;
    }
}
```

implemented this way to make sure the `request` is *never* null.

Now, I do give a lot of time for the vid to initialize, as it should load upon leve start, but it still doesn't do anything. No error, no freeze.

In the editor play, I tested it using `Debug.Log` and it reaches the code to actually call the ad. It just doesn't show up, whereas the banner ad works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not seeing any code for showing the ad in the above code snippet.
if (interstitial.IsLoaded()) {
    interstitial.Show();
  }

Comment: It was a good hint, but still no luck :/ I edit the question nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it now.

So the way I could make this work is this:

**I load the ads when I initialize the scene, or, to be exact, start the request right beforehand**. and hide them after the load.

And when I want the ads to show up, I just call the `Show()` method and boom, they are there.

My issue what that the internet speed ain't the best around here and I requested and wanted to show right after the request which won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Just give proper time to load the ad,  like for testing use the handler post delayed of 10 second to give time to load ad and after 10seconds ad will load.

To check you can simply use my same code in any activity

```
var adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()

    InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
            Log.d(TAG, adError?.message)
            mInterstitialAd = null
        }

        override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Ad was loaded.")
            mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
        }
    })


    Handler().postDelayed({
        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            println("executed")
            mInterstitialAd?.show(this)
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.")
        }
    }, 10000)
```